How to plot bar graph with button for multiple categories?
For a given dataframe, I am trying to create plotly plot a comparative bar graph with q1,q2.. on the x-axis, and barline for each stockname and the figures on y-axis.
Additionally, a button should have [Sales, Net Profit] selectors so that when an option is picked it should plot a comparative graph of those stocks (maximum 6 stocks).
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

my_dict = dict({
    'quarterly_result' : ['Sales','Net Profit', 'Sales', 'Net Profit'],
    'stockname' : ['Stock1', 'Stock1','Stock2', 'Stock2'],
    'q1' : [100,10,np.nan,np.nan],
    'q2' : [110,20.6,570,120],
    'q3' : [67,-2.0,620,125.7],
    'q4' : [125,40.5,np.nan,np.nan],
    'q5' : [np.nan,np.nan,660,105.9],
    'q6' : [np.nan,np.nan,636,140]
})

df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)

fig = go.Figure()

x = df.columns[2:]
y1 = df.loc[0][2:]
y2 = df.loc[2][2:]

fig.add_traces(go.Bar(x=x, y=y1))
fig.add_traces(go.Bar(x=x, y=y2))

buttons = [{'method': 'update', 'label': col, 'args': [{'y': [df[col]]}]} 
           for col in df.iloc[:, 1:]]

updatemenus = [{'buttons': buttons,
                'direction': 'down',
                'showactive': True,}]

# update layout with buttons, and show the figure
fig.update_layout(updatemenus=updatemenus)
fig.show()


I am unsure how to plot this multi-categorical dataframe. Below snippet is not working. How do I fix this?
Incorrect outcome:

Expected:


You can add traces for each stock with the respective metric. Then add buttons to toggle between the metrics:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

my_dict = {
    'quarterly_result': ['Sales', 'Net Profit', 'Sales', 'Net Profit'],
    'stockname': ['Stock1', 'Stock1', 'Stock2', 'Stock2'],
    'q1': [100, 10, np.nan, np.nan],
    'q2': [110, 20.6, 570, 120],
    'q3': [67, -2.0, 620, 125.7],
    'q4': [125, 40.5, np.nan, np.nan],
    'q5': [np.nan, np.nan, 660, 105.9],
    'q6': [np.nan, np.nan, 636, 140]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)

fig = go.Figure()

# List of quarters
x = df.columns[2:]

# Add traces for each metric
for result in df['quarterly_result'].unique():
    for stock in df['stockname'].unique():
        fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
            x=x,
            y=df[(df['stockname'] == stock) & (df['quarterly_result'] == result)].iloc[0, 2:],
            name=f'{stock} {result}'
        ))

# Add buttons to toggle the visibility
buttons = [{'label': label, 'method': 'update',
            'args': [{'visible': [label in trace.name for trace in fig.data]}]}
           for label in df['quarterly_result'].unique()]

updatemenus = [{'buttons': buttons,
                'direction': "down",
                'showactive': True, }]

# update layout with buttons, and show the figure
fig.update_layout(updatemenus=updatemenus)
fig.show()

Results:
Initial plot, both are visible:

Sales:

Net profit:


Not correct, When Sales button is selected, the bars corresponding to Sales only should be plotted for both stocks. But this is plotting Sales as well as Net Profit.

My bad, I used the wrong condition for buttons. Please see the updated answer.

Perfetct ! Thanks !
